# What is needed to run executable .jar file on windows and mac?

Tags: windows, macos, jar

I've exported my application from eclipse as executable .jar file. On my computer it works and fine as I double click it. Tommorow I will have to install this application on several computers of which some are osx and some are windows. What software will I also be needing to install to make my .jar executable by a double-click ?

Comment: You need to install a Java runtime on the Mac

Answer (score 0):

You need a minimum of a JRE (Java Runtime Environment) install.
See [Oracle's official download site for JREs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html)

It is likely that most machines have java JRE installed somewhere already. If you can find the `java` command in your path, you're (almost certainly) good to go.